# How do I use the WorkBench to retrieve metadata?

Tags: metadata, workbench

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve Field Audit Trail metadata using the WorkBench, and I'm stumped. I used the WorkBench to deploy a zip file named package-Dev.zip, which contained the following files:

1) A file named Account.object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <historyRetentionPolicy>
       <archiveAfterMonths>14</archiveAfterMonths>
       <archiveRetentionYears>10</archiveRetentionYears>
       <description>Account object field history retention policy -- Dev</description>
       <gracePeriodDays>0</gracePeriodDays>
   </historyRetentionPolicy>
   <fields>
       <fullName>BillingAddress</fullName>
       <fullName>City_Mailing_Address_Group__c</fullName>
   </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

2) A file named package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
    </types>
    <version>32.0</version>
</Package>
```

Now I want to use the WorkBench to retrieve the metadata (history retention policy and fields) that I deployed for the account object via package-Dev.zip. What's the XML code that I need to use to retrieve that metadata? I'm not an XML or API programmer, and all of the examples I've found seem to assume that I know more than I do, so I'm lost.

Answer (score 2):

On the top level menu click 'migration' and select the 'retrieve' option. The XML you'll need will be similar to the one used to deploy. Notice I'm using api version 36.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

You can find more info about this here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_history_retention.meta/field_history_retention/field_audit_trail.htm